# Python string rearranging

Tags: python, string, encryption

I am wanting to rearrange strings in python, but don understand what functions would be useful in doing so? Can someone help me understand how do this: remove the first letter of a word and place that letter at the end of the word. Then you append "IE" to the end of the word. I would appreciate it, if someone can link to the functions that might be used, so I can learn how they work.

**EDIT:** I have tried to make this work with a phrase, but I am having issues with getting it to the ie to go at the end of the words. For example HankTIE ouYIE would be the output of the input Thank You.

Here is what I have:

```
string = input("Please input a word: ")
def silly_encrypter(string):
    words = string.split()
    for words in string:
        first_letter= words[1:] + words[0]
        ie_end = first_letter + "IE"
        print (ie_end)

silly_encrypter(string)
```

Comment: I suggest you read the tutorial at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Comment: I know it's not generally an acceptable response to tell people to google something. But the top response for "python remove letter from string" is a nice article called "5 Ways to Remove a Character from String in Python" -

Comment: I'm voting to close this as the current code doesn't seem to have the problem as described, it seems a copy of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As other users pointed out, I strongly suggest you to read Python tutorial, which is very friendly and contains a lot of examples that you can try out in your `python` console.

Having said that, you could take advantage of string `indexing` plus `concatenation` to accomplish the things you want (Both things are mentioned in the tutorial):

> remove the first letter of a word and place that letter at the end of the word:

```py
s = "myString"

first_letter_at_the_end = s[1:] + s[0]
# If you print `first_at_the_end` you'll get: 'yStringm'
```

> then append "IE" at the end

```py
ie_at_the_end = first_letter_at_the_end + "IE"
# If you print `ie_at_the_end` you'll get: 'yStringmIE'
```

Comment: This was helpful! Thank you for providing examples.